# Mongoose population does not populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

the population not working in below code.. what should I do?
I want to populate this 'Stall' model with his Exhibitor. (ExhibitorID).

this is the model

```
const stall = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        default:'Stall Name'
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        default:'Stall Description'
    },
    logoImage:{
        type:String,
        default:'/public/images/logoImage.jpg'
    },
    exhibitorID:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Exhibitor'
    },
    eventID:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Event'
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stall',stall)
```

this is the route

```
router.get('/all/:eventID',eventAdminAuth,async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        var ob = await event.findById(req.params.eventID)
        var stalls = await stall.find({eventID:req.params.eventID}).populate('Exhibitor')
        console.log(stalls)
        if(ob){
            res.locals.event=ob
            res.render('eventSettings/stalls',{stalls:stalls})
        }else{
            res.send('no event')
        }
    }catch(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stalls query should be something like below:

```
var stalls = await stall.find({eventID:req.params.eventID}).populate('exhibitorID')
console.log(stalls)
```

Since you have referenced the "Exhbibitor" with the entry "exhibitorID", you should used that field in the .polupate() function's arguement.